# Login form is not working correctly

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a little issue with my login form. I think the problem is mysqli code because when the code was old mysql code, the login worked correctly but since I changed it to mysqli, it has not quite worked properly.

What is suppose to happen is that the user will enter in their username and password in the login form, when the user clicks on the "Login" button, it will check in the database if the username and password is correct. If it is correct then navigate to the menu.php page else if login is incorrect, display a message stating log in is incorrect, try again.

Instead what the code below is doing is that when the user enters in their username and password and clicks on "Login" button, no matter if username and password is correct or not it just refreshes the from, it doesn't navigate to menu.php page or display a login incorrect message.

So my question is that why is this happening, why after logging in does it not navigate the user or display the incorrect login message?

Below is the code:

```
 <?php

    session_start(); 

    $username="xxx";
    $password="xxx";
    $database="xxx";

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database)or die( "Unable to select database");

    foreach (array('teacherusername','teacherpassword') as $varname) {
            $$varname = (isset($_POST[$varname])) ? $_POST[$varname] : '';
          }

    ?>

    <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id="teachLoginForm">        
    <p>Username</p><p><input type="text" name="teacherusername" /></p>      <!-- Enter Teacher Username-->
    <p>Password</p><p><input type="password" name="teacherpassword" /></p>  <!-- Enter Teacher Password--> 
    <p><input id="loginSubmit" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" /></p>
    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $query = $mysqli->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM Teacher t  
    WHERE 
    (t.TeacherUsername = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($teacherusername)."')
    AND
    (t.TeacherPassword = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($teacherpassword)."')
    ");

    $query->bind_result($Teacher);

    $num = $query->num_rows($result = $query->execute());

    $loged = false;

    while($row = $result->fetch())
      {

          if ($_POST['teacherusername'] == ($row['TeacherUsername']) && $_POST['teacherpassword'] == ($row['TeacherPassword']))
          {
              $loged = true;
          }

$_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $row['TeacherForename'];
$_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $row['TeacherSurname'];
$_SESSION['teacherusername'] = $row['TeacherUsername'];

      }

      if ($loged == true){
      header( 'Location: menu.php' ) ;
    }else{
      echo "The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again.";
    }


    }
     ?>
```

Comment: This `header( 'Location: menu.php' ) ;` will not work under any circumstances since you have already sent data (the HTML).  Ensure you have error reporting on since this flaw would result in a PHP error like "Cannot send headers; output already sent"

Comment: @jedwards So what do I need to do to get the if statement to work so that if login is true then navigate to menu.php else display incorrect login message?

Comment: I wouldn't say "under any circumstances". Output buffering is enabled by default on some hosts, allowing you to use `header()` essentially whenever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is really bad for a number of reasons.  Let me try to rewrite this for you and explain why.

First off, you're getting and looping through ***all*** of the rows of the database and checking for a match, you should be doing this within your SQL query.

Second, you're trying to send headers after output is sent.  This won't work and should throw an error if you have error reporting enabled.

Third, you define the variables `$teacherusername` and `$teacherpassword` for no real reason, and don't even consistently use them.

Fourth, you're starting a session for seemingly no reason.

Fifth, your query is unnecessarily complicated.

Sixth, as pointed out by Mike, you're storing users passwords in the database as plaintext.

I'd write this as:

```
<?php
// There can be nothing (HTML, whitespace, anything) above this php tag.

if(isset($_POST['teacherusername']) && isset($_POST['teacherpassword']))
{
    // Connect to Database
    $username="xxx";
    $password="xxx";
    $database="xxx";
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database)or die( "Unable to select database");

    // Build Query
    $q = sprintf('SELECT * FROM Teacher t');
    $q.= sprintf(' WHERE t.TeacherUsername = %s', mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['teacherusername']));
    $q.= sprintf(' AND t.TeacherPassword = %s', mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['teacherpassword']));

    // Run Query
    $query->bind_result($Teacher);
    $res = $query->execute();
    $num = $query->num_rows();

    if($num == 1)
    {
        header('Location: menu.php' );
    }
    else
    {
        session_start();        // Do you need this?
        echo "The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again.";
    }
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id="teachLoginForm">        
<p>Username</p><p><input type="text" name="teacherusername" /></p>      <!-- Enter Teacher Username-->
<p>Password</p><p><input type="password" name="teacherpassword" /></p>  <!-- Enter Teacher Password--> 
<p><input id="loginSubmit" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Now, this doesn't resolve the fact that you're still storing passwords in the database as plaintext.  That's bad practice, but kind of outside the scope of today's lesson :-)

Here, the PHP is run first, and either `header()` or `session_start()` is the first thing that sends output -- this is important as they both need to be the first thing to send output.

I also resolved you're validation loop.  If the query returns rows then there are matches in the database and the username and password is correct, no need to loop.

Comment: You forgot to mention storing passwords in plain text

Comment: I like to thank in advance for your help, I tried to change my old mysql code to mysqli code as I heard it is better yet it works for my version of php 5.2.13. I must of done a bad job but thank you for helping me and I am looking forward to seeing the code you are going to show me :)

Comment: The query isn't pulling all the rows from the database; it has a WHERE clause that matches only a record with the right username and password.  Checking the username and password *again* while processing the results is redundant — all it needs to care about is whether the query returned a row — but it's not harmful.

Comment: @Wyzard, you're right -- I realized that too when I was rewriting it.  Thanks

Comment: @jedwards hi, i am getting an error where you have placed the if isset at the top where it states: `syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ',' or ')`

Comment: @jedwards BTW this is completely my fault but the reason there was a session_start() in the code was because if the user does log in successfully, it would retrieve the username, forename and surname of the user and display it in another page using $_SESSION. I removed this from the original code thinking you did not need to see it but it is needed somewhere in your code. I updated the old code in my question to display where the $_SESSION's were displayed in the old code but where would these $_SESSIONs be displayed in your code?

Comment: Just an observation, if you're using `mysqli`, why not take advantage of prepared statements similar to how the OP did in his question, however actually bind the parameters correctly? This is one of the main advantages over regular `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: re error: change this `if(isset($_POST['teacherusername'] && isset($_POST['teacherpassword'])))` to `if(isset($_POST['teacherusername']) && isset($_POST['teacherpassword']))` -- I'll fix it in my code as well

Comment: I have tried your code but now it just displays a blank screen, don't I need a if isset 'submit' somewhere?

Comment: You should make sure error reporting is turned on then.  You're getting an error that's causing the script to end early -- need to know what it is.